# which parts of asp.net website are shared between users?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net website project, is pages and .cs files compile for each and every client ?
how can I learn this sort of information is there any resource? 
which parts of website are shared between users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is only one copy of the web site for all users.

There is only one copy of any `static` (`Shared` in VB.NET) data, for all users, so be careful. Some developers assume that these values will magically be turned into per-session variables, but no. (I used to think that way, then learned).

If using `Session` state, then each browser session will have one copy of `Session`. This is cookie-based, so the same user using IE and FireFox will have two sessions.

Each request to a page creates a new instance of the `Page` class and any controls on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Pages and cs files are compiled by the server (or they can be pre-compiled using Visual Studio) and they are served to each client according to the request as HTML.

Re-compilation of the code is caused by changes in the bin folder or web.config file and not by different users accessing the pages.

I admit that I don't fully understand the question, but if you are talking about common data or "global variables" of the legacy type, then I can add that there are session-wide variables and application-wide variables. Application wide variables retain the same values for all users as long as the application is running.

Answer (score -1):

asp.net is session based, you get new pages and variables/objects per session, so every user gets his own 'session' of the website unless he hijacks someone else's session.

if you want to share a variable/object between users, declare it as static. you can make singleton classes which are also shared between users.

Comment: Yeah, but you're still not quite right about how sessions work. Pages and variables are not related to sessions.